# Error retrieving folder name from server using TIdFTP

Tags: c++, firemonkey, c++builder, indy

My task is to access an FTP server and go through all its folders and subfolders. I use the `TIdFTP` component, implementing the code:

```
TIdFTP *Ftp = new TIdFTP();

Ftp->Host     = Dir;
Ftp->Port     = Prt;
Ftp->Username = Usr;
Ftp->Password = Key;
Ftp->Passive  = true;

//Conect
if(!Ftp->Connected())
{
    try
    {
        Ftp->Connect();
        //Descarga
        Treewalk()
        ....
    }

...

void TWallk::Treewalk()
{
    try
    {
        Ftp->ChangeDir("//");
        ListDats();
    }
    catch (...)
    {
    }
}

void TWallk::ListDats()
{
    std::auto_ptr<TStringList> Elements (new TStringList);
    Ftp->List(Elements.get());
    int NumElemnt = Ftp->DirectoryListing->Count;
    int Pos;
    bool *IsDir = new  bool[NumElemnt];

    for (int i=2;i<NumElemnt;i++)
    {
        AnsiString pa =  Elements->Strings[i];
        TIdFTPListItem*  ListItem = Ftp->DirectoryListing->Items[i];
        Elementos->Strings[i] = ListItem->FileName;
        FechAlla[i] = ListItem->ModifiedDate;
        IsDir[i]=ListItem->ItemType == ditDirectory;
    }
    ...
}
```

On Windows platform, it shows all folders and files perfectly.

On Android platform, I access the server perfectly and check the directory, but the problem is that two elements (folders) are not showing, and instead it names two elements as `".."` and `"."`; the rest of the names are perfect.

Any ideas?

Comment: `..` is the parent directory and `.` is the current directory. They are not hiding two other directory elements. Just disregard them.

Comment: `std::auto_ptr` makes me think that you are using "the classic" compiler. Unless you are maintaining an old project, I recommend upgrading by unselecting the classic compiler and instead use the clang enhanced compiler which lets you write a lot more modern C++.

Comment: Thanks for answering..

Correct, the code is recovered from an old script in c++ builder 6 .. What I don't understand is that working with firemonkey the number of elements that it tells me are on the server is correct but two of them that are folders are not detected The other folders and files yes.

Comment: You start iterating from the third element in `for (int i=2;i<NumElemnt;i++)` so what are the two you are skipping? I would loop from `0` and print all and just skip `.` and `..`.

Comment: On a side note: there is no point in creating the `TStringList` at all since you are not using it for anything meaningful. You are using `TIdFTP::DirectoryListing` instead. So, you can get rid of the `TStringList` altogether and just pass null to `TIdFTP::List()`. Also, what is the point of using a smart pointer for the `TStringList`, but not using a smart container for the `IsDir` array? You should use `std::vector` for that array and get rid of `new[]`.

Comment: Thank you very much to both of you, You have been a great help. The problem I had wasn't code, it was my stupidity... Ted's comment: "You start iterating from the third element in for (int i=2;i<NumElemnt;i++) so what are the two you are skipping? I would loop from 0 and print all and just skip . and .."  It opened my eyes.. Indeed, the positions 0 and 1 correspond to the "lost" elements. (in plataform windows 0 and 1 they corresponded to ".." and "." so the loop would start at 2). I have tested Remy's code and it works perfectly as always.
Thank you and forgive my English.

Answer (score 2):

As @TedLyngmo mentioned in [this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75512812/error-retrieving-folder-name-from-server-using-tidftp-component#comment133231676_75512812), you are not iterating through the `DirectoryListing` correctly.  You are unconditionally skipping the 1st two items. A server *may or may not* return `.` and `..` as actual items, that is at the server's discretion.

You should do something more like this instead:

```
void TWallk::ListDats()
{
    Ftp->List(NULL);

    int NumItems = Ftp->DirectoryListing->Count;
    int NumElemnt = 0;

    std::vector<bool> IsDir;
    IsDir.reserve(NumItems);

    for (int i = 0; i < NumElemnt; ++i)
    {
        TIdFTPListItem* ListItem = Ftp->DirectoryListing->Items[i];

        String pa = ListItem->FileName;
        if (pa == _D(".") || pa = _D("..")) continue;

        Elementos->Strings[NumElemnt] = pa;
        FechAlla[NumElemnt] = ListItem->ModifiedDate;
        IsDir.push_back(ListItem->ItemType == ditDirectory);
        ++NumElemnt;
        ...
    }
    ...
}
```